# scala named parameter in function-as-params?

Tags: scala

I'm quite used to Typescript's function-with-param-names as function-params:

```
function doHello(
    helloFunc: (lastName: string, firstName: string) => void,
    ...
) { ... }
```

Here, helloFunc describes a function-as-param with 'named' params (lastName, firstName)

but I could only find examples without param-names, such as:

```
case class HelloWoot(
    helloFunc: (String, String) => Unit,
    ...
)
```

which omits some info about helloFunc signature.

So, how do I get the following code to compile in Scala?

```
case class HelloWoot(
    helloFunc: (lastName: String, firstName: String) => Unit,
    // Error
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to provide named parameters in a higher order function.  If you are worried about people mixing up the String parameters you could introduce a new type like this:

```
// New object with firstName and lastName
case class NamesObject(firstName: String, lastName: String)

// Higher order function now takes the new type as input
case class HelloWoot(helloFunc: (NamesObject) => Unit)

// You can now safely access the correct variable without having to rely on their order in the Tuple2
HelloWoot(a => println(a.firstName, a.lastName))
```

Comment: did scala disable providing named params in higher-order functions by design? or is this a 'bug' or a missing feature of scala?

Comment: I suspect its because you are just defining the type of the parameter, and in this case the type just happens to be a function that is the type `(String, String) => Unit`

Comment: I guess that might be the reason scala made it that way... but that seems to omit too much info about the code...

hope scala people would care more about variable names... using names like 'm' and writing a book that says 'monoid is a word that begins with m, so this must be monoid!' is utter madness :(